# warning_cast.c: In function ?fn_print?: warning_cast.c:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

warning_cast.c: In function ?fn_print?:
warning_cast.c:5: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fn_print(unsigned int a)
{
    printf("val = %d\n", *((unsigned int *)a));
}

int main()
{
    fn_print(10000);
}
```

Comment: What do you intend to do by `*((unsigned int *)a)`?

Comment: in fn_print(<passing address calculated by adding offset to the base address>), i need to access the value in that address

Comment: What are you expecting at address 10000?

Comment: actually, this is model question, i need the get the value from the address that is passed to the function as value..

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`printf("val = %d\n", *((unsigned int *)a));`  <--Cast Integer to a int pointer

With

`printf("val = %d\n", *((unsigned int *)&a));` <-- Cast Address to int pointer

EDIT:

Based on comment:

This may remove warning in function `fn_printf`

```
void fn_print(unsigned int* a)
{
    printf("val = %d\n", *a);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = 10000;
    fn_print((unsigned int*)x);
}
```

If you are asking how to mute compiler warnings then my answer is Do Not Do It.

Comment: in fn_print(<passing address calculated by adding offset to the base address>), i need to access the value in that address

Comment: have to suppress the warning while Casting Integer to a int pointer, how to achieve that.

Comment: Don't suppress it its telling you you're doing something bad.

Comment: void fn_print(unsigned int* a)
{
    printf("val = %d\n", *a);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int x = 10000;
    fn_print((unsigned int*)x);
}     getting warning again

Comment: @user2902744 Your code in above comment and my answer have few major differences,please copy carefully.

Comment: rooney, dont like to suppress, would like to know abt is there any way to fix this warning?

Comment: @vagish, this is the actual one i am doing, sorry for the changes in posted question, will change the question too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this. You pass the address to `fn_print` and dereference the pointer using * operator inside the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fn_print(unsigned int* a)
{
    printf("at address %p we have value %u\n", a, *a);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 10000;

    fn_print(&a);
}
```

The warning you are facing is because when you cast from `unsigned int` to `unsigned int*` you are casting between types of differing sizes on your system (64 bit right?).

To convince yourself of this try

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("sizeof(unsigned int)=%u\n", sizeof(unsigned int));
    printf("sizeof(unsigned int*)=%u\n", sizeof(unsigned int*));
}
```

Comment: actually, this is model question, i need the get the value from the address that is passed to the function as value.

Comment: i should not got get the warning for that how it is possible?